# Populate the values of previous row in current row Oracle view

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below.

Now I want a view  where for each row, the values in column `START_DATE` should be the values in `END_DATE` of the previous row. (Ignore the 1st row alone for view creation  which i will populate with junk value or null value).

Any suggestions please. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please post table definitions and sample data as text, not as images. Ideally include a http:://sqlfiddle.com example.

Comment: Sorry i though image would be clear to explain.

Comment: look up LAG functions

Answer (score 3):

```
select value1,
       lag(end_date) over (order by end_date) as start_date,
       end_date
from the_table;
```

If there is no "previous" row (based on the sort order defined by the `order by`) then the `lag()` function returns `NULL`.

If you don't want the `NULL` value but something else instead for the first row, you can supply a default value for the `lag()` function:

```
select value1,
       lag(end_date,1, DATE '2014-01-01') over (order by end_date) as start_date,
       end_date
from the_table;
```

Comment: Hi..End date is the column in table...i want the column start date in my view

Comment: @VinodChelladurai: then just swap the names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.EndDate, Max(s.EndDate) as StartDate
FROM TableName t 
  LEFT JOIN TableName s ON t.EndDate> s.EndDate
GROUP BY t.ID, t.EndDate
```